# Regex with start and end match

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm having trouble matching the start and end of a regex on Python.
Essentially I'm confused about the when to use word boundaries `/b` and start/end anchors `^ $`

My regex of

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}
```

matches 4 letter characters (two uppercase letters, two digits) which is what I'm after

Matches AJ99, RD22, CP44 etc

However, I also noted that AJAJAJAJAJAJAJAJAJSJHS99 could be matched as well. I've tried used ^ and $ together to match the whole string. This doesn't work

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}$ # this doesn't work
```

but

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2} # this is fine 
[A-Z]{2}\d{2}$ # this is fine
```

The string I'm matching against is 4 characters long, but in the first two examples the regex could pick the start and end of a longer string respectively.

```
s = "NZ43" # 4 characters, match perfect! However....
s = "AM27272727" # matches the first example 
s = "HAHSHSHSHDS57" # matches the second example
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a string that fails? In fact some that fail and some that succeed would help.

Comment: what exactly do you want to match? posting some sample inputs and their respective matches would help a lot.

Comment: yes, that looks correct. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position anchors `^` and `$` place a restriction on the position of your matched chars:

Analyzing your complete regex:

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}$
```

- `^` matches only at the beginning of the text
- `[A-Z]{2}` exactly 2 uppercase Ascii alphabetic characters
- `\d{2}` exactly 2 digits (equivalent to `[0-9]{2}`)
- `$` matches only at the end of the text

If you remove one or both of the 2 position anchors (`^` or `$`) you can match a substring starting from the beginning or the end as you stated above.

If you want to match exactly a word without using the start/end of the string use the `\b` anchor, like this:

```
``\b[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\b``
```

- `\b` matches at the start/end of text and between a regex **word** (in regex a word char `\w` is intended as one of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and one char **not** in the word group (available as `\W`).

The regex above **matches** `WS24` in all the next strings:

- `WS24` alone
- `before WS24`
- `WS24 after`
- `before WS24 after`
- `NZ43`

It **doesn't match**:

- `AM27272727` (it will do if is `AM27 272727` or `AM27"272727`
- `HAHSHSHSHDS57` (it will do if `HAHSHSHSH DS75` or...you get it)

A [demo online](https://regex101.com/r/kN9dB3/2) (the site will be useful to you also to experiment with regex).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your shown behaviour is like it's supposed to be, your question suggests that you maybe does not have fully understood how regular expressions work.

As a addition to the very good and informative answer of GsusRecovery, [here](http://regexone.com/)'s a site, that guides you through the concepts of regular expressions and tries to teach you the basics with a lessons-based system. To be clear, I do not want to tout this website, as there are plenty of those, but however I could really made a use of this one and so it's the one I'm suggesting.